# MongoDB best for this one to many use case? Or relational instead?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database, nosql

I've been studying MongoDb [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Document References](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/). With the pattern below, I find it troubling that if I want to query for all the records that belong to `oreilly`, I would have to actually query all the records in existance.

In contrast, in a relational DB like mysql, I would have a primary key on `oreilly` and foriegn keys on the records. Then I would only have to query all the publishers(which would be less than all the book records) for `oreilly`, instead of all the book records(which would be more than publishers) that exist to find the ones that belong to `oreilly`.

Am I seeing this correctly? Would this use case be better for a relational DB?

```
{
   _id: "oreilly",
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA"
}

{
   _id: 123456789,
   title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
   author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
   published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
   pages: 216,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}

{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English",
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}
```

Comment: It's better to use **_type** or store this data in separate collections.

Comment: Read your own text _carefully_: You'd need a foreign key. Which translates to querying _two_ tables. Simply put an index on `publisher_id` and you only have to query one collection, and efficiently so. Further reading: http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/#why-would-one-use-embedding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an index on `{ publisher_id: 1 }` on your book collection, you can greatly speed up finding the book documents with a specific publisher. A [hashed index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/#index-type-hashed) (`{ publisher_id: "hashed }`) might be even faster on a large dataset, but only speeds up queries for exact equality while an ascending index gives you some additional features like alphabetic sorting or searching by the beginning of the string.

By the way: JOINs in a relational database aren't magic. The exact same thing happens internally. The database looks up the matching entries of the first table and then scans the second table for entries which match the join-condition for the entries of the first, ideally using an index. Defining a secondary key in a relational database doesn't do much more than adding an index on those fields.